# Why UM Typewriter font not working properly?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, minted, typewriter, syntax-highlighting

I compiled this code

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted, fontspec}

\setmonofont{UM Typewriter} %% <--- some problems here (see the next comment). To solve comment it out.

\begin{document}

%% $ sign overlaps a
\begin{minted}{R}
# print(acf(wind_speed, lag.max = lag, plot = FALSE)$acf) 
\end{minted}
    
\begin{minted}{R}
print(acf(wind_speed, lag.max = lag, plot = FALSE)$acf)
\end{minted}
    
\begin{minted}{R}
# print(acf(wind_speed, lag.max = lag, plot = FALSE)$ acf)
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

whith

```bash
latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -synctex=1 -lualatex foo.tex
```

and this is the result[image: wrong result]
So for my purpose as workaround I added a space between `$` and `acf`. But I think it is a weak solution, is there another robust? Are there other cases where this bug rises?

Thanks in advance,
Lorenzo.

## Edit

If I change code like below Marcel's answer doesn't work.

```tex
\documentclass{toptesi} %% <--- I changed THIS
\usepackage{fontspec}

% First define the feature. We set the width to the width of the space since the font is monospace
\directlua{
  fonts.constructors.features.otf.register{
    name = 'fix_umt_width',
    description = 'Overwrite width value of dollar in UM Typewriter',
    manipulators = {
      node = function(tfmdata)
        tfmdata.characters[\number`\$].width=tfmdata.parameters.space
      end,
    },
  }
}

% Then use it in the fontspec call
\setmonofont[RawFeature=+fix_umt_width]{UM Typewriter}

\begin{document}

\textit{\texttt{\string$acf}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I contacted Apostolos Syropoulos, the author of the font and he has submitted a new version to ctan, and confirmed it fixes this issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you!. So I wait tomorrow morning to update my TeX release.

Comment: it can take a few days for releases to get from ctan to all mirrors of texlive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As David wrote, you can fix this on the fly in LuaLaTeX by adding a feature to change the glyph width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% First define the feature. We set the width to the width of the space since the font is monospace
\directlua{
  fonts.constructors.features.otf.register{
    name = 'fix_umt_width',
    description = 'Overwrite width value of dollar in UM Typewriter',
    manipulators = {
      node = function(tfmdata)
        tfmdata.characters[\number`\$].width=tfmdata.parameters.space
      end,
    },
  }
}

% Then use it in the fontspec call
\setmonofont[RawFeature=+fix_umt_width]{UM Typewriter}

\begin{document}

\textit{\texttt{\string$acf}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But if I use `\documentclass{toptesi}` it doesn't work anymore. See my edit for more details.

Comment: @LorenzoFerron `polyglossia` grmmble... use `\setmonofont[Renderer=Node,RawFeature=+fix_umt_width]{UM Typewriter}`

Answer (score 5):

it is not minted, the italic version of the font produces:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{UM Typewriter} %% <--- some problems here (see the next comment). To solve comment it out.


 
\begin{document}

\textit{\texttt{\string$acf\showthe\font}}

\end{document}
```

adding `` \showthe\fontcharwd\font`\$ `` produces

`> 0.0pt.`

so the `$` is zero width.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. But I don't understand if this is a bug or a feature of font.

Comment: @LorenzoFerron bug in the font I guess, also you can change the metric "on the fly" in Lua except I got that wrong when I tried, I may update later, I'll ping you here if so.

Comment: @LorenzoFerron can you move the tick to Marcel's answer, so people get led to the right code